# How to set Virtual Table(Inserted and Deleted) Values in Trigger

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers

I am updating a table called A when update event occurs the trigger is fired. My requirement is I need to insert the datas to another table(from A to B) and values for that table is attained from virtual tables (Deleted and Inserted). How to set inserted and deleted virtual table values

**TRIGGER**

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgAfterUpdate ON A
FOR UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
Insert into B(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5) values ()  // col1 to 4 inserted values col5 Deleted table value
END
```

Comment: Does table `A` have a primary key?

Comment: @GarethD Yes Primary key with auto identity

Answer (score 1):

```
Insert B(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5) 
select inserted.col1, inserted.col2, inserted.col3, inserted.col4, deleted.col5
from inserted
     inner join deleted on inserted.IDField = deleted.IDField
```

Comment: So your code will look like "Insert into B(col1,col2,...) values(select inserted.col1,...from inserted inner join deleted on inserted.col5= deleted.col5)" is it right?

Comment: If col5 is the unique ID, then it shouldn't normally be changing, so why do you need the deleted table?

Answer (score 0):

I worked on same type project where i have to take regular updates after certain time and insert this in table but table should contain all unique value...to solve this i did following.

1. took two table of similar entities.
2. in one of the table i took all the value and after this i compare this to other table to get duplicate data and after this delete it and then insert it to new table by copying table form one to another..

---

```
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("delete table2 from table2 inner join tabl1 on table1.some entries=table2.on same entry", connection_object);       
cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand("insert into table1 (all values) select all values from table2", connection_object);
cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection_object.Close();
```